# Search Box - how it open in code

Tags: android, search

is any way how I can start/open search box with codes or its possible just with click on search key?

Answer (score 3):

```
SearchManager mgr = ((SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE));
mgr.startSearch(null, false, getComponentName(), null, false);
```

will do the trick.